# How can we replace of string's specific area with a keyword -PHP

Tags: php

I want to replace of string's  spesific area with `"*"`. I tried to PHP `substr_replace`  but it doesnt work for me.

I have a name like this:

```
Jhon Smith
```

I want to show only name and last name's start letter.I want to change other letters with `"*"`.

So Output should like this:

```
J*** S****
```

How can I do this with PHP?

Comment: would you like to show the code you have tried? and what were the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex and [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

```
<?php

$name = 'John Smith';

$name = preg_replace_callback('/\w+/u', function($match) {
    return $match[0][0] . str_repeat('*', strlen($match[0]) - 1);
}, $name);

var_dump($name);
// string(10) "J*** S****"
```

[**DEMO**](https://eval.in/254930)

### How does it work?

`\w+` matches a "*word*" (a-z, A-Z, 0-9) and the anonymous method returns the first letter of the word (`match[0][0]`) followed by the character `*` repeated by the length of the word (`match[0]`) minus one.

The `/u` modifier species unicode. It's so we also match names such as `Günther`.

That means that `match[0][0]` would be eg. "J" in "John" and "S" in "Smith" and the length minus one would be "3" for "John" and 4 for "Smith".

Comment: @coder3 I missed a slight thing when I posted, that I've edited now. Remember to use the `u` modifier in the regex (`/w+/u` instead of `/w+/`). Otherwise `Günther Smith` (and other unicode names) become `Gün**** S****`. [With the `/u` modifier this does not happen](https://eval.in/254934).

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways you can do this. I have written you a small helper function that will accomplish what you're needing.

```
function cleanName($string = 'Jhon Smith')
{
    // Get all the pieces of the name
    $pieces = explode(' ', $string);

    // Loop through each piece and replace asterisks where necessary
    foreach($pieces as $key => $value)
    {
        // Get the length of the string
        $length = strlen($value);

        // Calculate how many asterisks are needed
        $asterisks = $length - 1;

        // Show / start with the first letter of the string
        $name = substr($value, 0, 1);

        // Add the asterisks to the end of the string
        for($i = 1; $i <= $asterisks; $i++)
        {
            $name .= '*';
        }

        // Create the name 'part'
        $parts[] = $name;
    }

    // Recreate the name
    $name = implode(' ', $parts);

    echo $name;
}
```

You can use this by calling the function and replacing the string on each occurrence:

`cleanName('Jane Smith');`

There are other ways of accomplishing this such as using regular expressions. Considering that you sound a bit new to the subject, I'm assuming you don't know regular expressions, particularly [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php), so I strayed away from it.

Comment: replace `echo` with `return`

Comment: @r3wt The string is being output to the browser, thus `echo`. Your reasoning for `return`?

Comment: its a matter of spaghetti

Comment: @r3wt not quite, perhaps you should research the differences between the two.

Answer (score 0):

for shoots and giggles, i made a function out of @h2ooooooo 's answer, trying to find the most efficient way possible to manipulate the string.

```
function cleanName($string)
{
    return implode(' ',
        array_map(function($substr){
            return mb_strtoupper(substr($substr,0,1)).str_repeat('*',(strlen($substr) - 1));
        },
            explode(' ', $string)
        )
    );
}
```

[phpFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/lite?code=%3C?php%5Cn%5Cnfunction%20cleanName($string)%5Cn%7B%5Cn%5Ctreturn%20implode(%27%20%27,%5Cn%5Ct%5Ctarray_map(function($substr)%7B%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ctreturn%20substr($substr,0,1).str_repeat(%27*%27,(strlen($substr)%20-%201%20));%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%7D,%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ctexplode(%27%20%27,$string)%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct)%5Cn%5Ct);%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cnecho%20cleanName(%27Test%20User%27);%5Cn%5Cn?%3E)